# Bitwise operator in array index php

Tags: php, arrays, indexing, bit-manipulation

I have received a piece of data look like this

```
"siteService": "1|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9".
```

The purpose of this data is for indexing a series of site services that users and select and the data will be varied depending on what the user is selecting so it can also be:

```
"siteService": "1|2|3|4|5"
```

So I created a look up array like this:

```
$siteServiceLookup = [
            1 => 'service',
            2 => 'service',
            3 => 'service',
            4 => 'service',
            5 => 'service',
            6 => 'service',
            7 => 'service',
            8 => 'service',
            9 => 'service',
            10 => 'service',
            11 => 'service',
            12 => 'service',
            13 => 'service',
            14 => 'service',
            15 => 'service',
            16 => 'service',
            17 => 'service',
            18 => 'service',
            19 => 'service',
            20 => 'service',
            21 => 'service',
            22 => 'service',
            23 => 'service',
            24 => 'service',
        ];
```

What I need to do is to select the service only when users selected and the series of numbers created for "siteService" are representing the service users are selecting.

The data is coming from another developer, I think he wants me to use the series numbers as the index so I iterate it through my array but I don't get what will the bitwise operators do in an array index. I cannot get in touch with him any time soon and my deadline is coming.  Can anyone help please?

Comment: Its is not totally clear what you want from us in your question

Comment: For example, if the user data is "siteService" : "1|3|5|7|10|11", I want that in my loop up array, only 1 => 'service', 3 => 'service', 5 => 'service', 7 => 'service',10 => 'service',11 => 'service' are selected so it can be displayed in my form.

Comment: Well thats just a simple foreach loop

Comment: This has nothing to do with bitwise operators. The '|' is just a list separator, the code would be the same if it was ',' or a line break, or the word " and ".

Answer (score 1):

A simple foreach loop is all you need

```
$siteServiceLookup = [
    1 => 'service1', 2 => 'service2', 3 => 'service3', 4 => 'service4', 5 => 'service5',
    6 => 'service6', 7 => 'service7', 8 => 'service', 9 => 'service', 10 => 'service',
    11 => 'service11', 12 => 'service12', 13 => 'service13', 14 => 'service14', 15 => 'service15',
    16 => 'service16', 17 => 'service17', 18 => 'service18', 19 => 'service19', 20 => 'service20',
    21 => 'service21', 22 => 'service22', 23 => 'service23', 24 => 'service24',];

$input = '1|3|5';
$wanted = explode('|', $input);

foreach ( $wanted as $key ) {
    echo $siteServiceLookup[$key] . PHP_EOL;
}
```

RESULT

```
service1
service3
service5
```